# How can I create my personal ToList() function for static arrays

Tags: c#

I must create `ToDynamic()` function for all types of static arrays,which returns a new dynamic list consisting of the elements of the array from which the function was called (just like `ToList()` works), like this:

```
int [] x = {1,2,3,4};
List<int> arr = x.ToDynamic();
```

Comment: or just `List<int> arr = new List<int>(x);`

Comment: That depends on where that `ToDynamic()` extension method comes from... Hit F12 and look what assembly it's from and try to find its source (or get ReSharper to decompile it for you).

Comment: I tried like this but it's false`
<pre>public static List<T> ToDynamic(List<T> oldList)
{
List<T> newList = new List<T>();    
for (int i = oldList.Count-1; i >= 0; i --)
    {
    newList.Add(oldList[i]);
    }
    return newList;
}</pre>

Comment: @Suren you can find the source [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/b31308b03e8bd5bf779fb80fda71f31eb959fe0b/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L947). But what is it you are trying to archive with your own method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scheme of *extension methods* writing is

```
  // partial: often we have many extensions on collections (Tree, Aggregations etc.) 
  // which are implemented in different files
  public static partial class EnumerableExtensions {

    // IEnumerable<T> - choose argument's type being as much generic and basic as you can
    public static List<T> ToDinamic<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
      // Validate argument(s)
      if (null == source)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source)); // or return null or empty list 

      return new List<T>(source);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `x.ToList()` to do what you want. If you really want to implement this yourself, you could just write a generic extension method like this:

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static List<T> ToDynamic<T>(this T[] items)
        => new List<T>(items ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(items)));
}
```